# How to order a stacked bar plot by size within each facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet-wrap

I have faceted data where each facet is a collection of stacked bars. I want to order the fill within each stacked bar by the size of that fill, with larger values being on the bottom and smaller values at the top. Let's say I have the following data:

```
require(ggplot2)
big_votes_movies = movies[movies$votes > 50000,]
p = ggplot(big_votes_movies, aes(x=rating, y=votes, fill=factor(year))) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_wrap(~ Drama)
```

Unfortunately, I cannot simply order the levels of movies$year to have the larger values at the bottom, as that has a global effect and thus does not do each facet individually. Is it possible to order the stacks by size within each bar within each facet?

[image]

Comment: Not directly, no. One common approach is to create each panel separately and then use `grid.arrange` to place them together. Legends get tricky, though.

Comment: Yeah, the scale would need to remain the same and the legend would need to be the same, in addition to the same colored fill for each value. In addition, grid.arrange is not nearly as pretty.

Comment: Well, you don't have many options then. (With the usual caveat that anything is _technically_ possible if you include resorting to doing it directly in **grid**, but that would be quite complicated.)